# python triple quote string adding multiple variables

Tags: python, string

I am using python 2.7. I have a triple quote string that I want to add 4 variables into. That string will then be used in a post request that our REST API will handle. Below is the string, it is shortened bc it is over 500 line long:

```
curDate = str(datetime.datetime.now().year)+"/"+str(datetime.datetime.now().month)+"/"+str(datetime.datetime.now().day)\
          +" "+str(datetime.datetime.now().hour)+":"+str(datetime.datetime.now().minute)+":"\
          +str(datetime.datetime.now().second)

...

payload = '''
   ...
"CaptureTime": %(captureTime),
   ...
"dataTime1": %(dataTime1)
   ...
"dataTime2": %(dataTime2)
   ...
"dataTime3": %(dataTime3)
   ...
"dataTime4": %(dataTime4)
   ...
''' % dict(captureTime=curDate, dataTime1=curDate, dataTime2=curDate, dataTime3=curDate, dataTime4=curDate)
```

This is the error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/xxx/xxxx/xxxxxx/Rest/Post.py", line 6130, in <module>
    ''' % {'captureTime':curDate, 'dataTime1':curDate, 'dataTime2':curDate, 'dataTime3':curDate, 'dataTime4':curDate}
ValueError: unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 204
```

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: You are evaluating `datetime.datetime.now()` multiple times for no reason. It returns a `namedtuple`. Just evaluate once and give it a name and make it efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proble is you use:

```
%(captureTime),
```

Instead of qualifying the type (I assume you are trying to qualify as string):

```
%(captureTime)s,
```

And so the comma is not recognized as type qualifier for %.